# how to call signal producer that depend to different signal producer in reactivecocoa4

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-cocoa

I have 2 signal producer like this

```
func textSignal() -> SignalProducer(String?,NoError)
```

and

```
func searchSignal(text:String) -> SignalProducer([User]?,NSError)
```

how to call searchSignal without nested function? since `flatmap`  & `attemptMap` need the same error result like this case is `NoError` and `NSError`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 type differences that one must fix to be able to compose both functions.

The original signal can carry nils, and the function you're trying to `flatMap` it with doesn't accept `nil`s. The type system is telling you that you need to choose a policy as to what to do in those cases. Some options:

- Filter nils:

`textSignal.filter { $0 != nil }.map { $0! }`

Not recommended because you'll ignore those values, so if the user searches for "foo", and then the text field produces a nil string, the app would still show the search results for "foo".

- Make the search function allow nils: this would be easy to do, but you're really just shifting the problem over to the other function, which would have to handle the nil values.
- Treat nil strings as empty strings

`textSignal.map { $0 ?? "" }`

This is probably the simplest and the one that produces the most natural results.

The second difference is the error type. The original signal doesn't produce errors, but the second one can. Using the `promoteErrors` function we can turn the first function from `NoError` to `NSError` like this:

`textSignal.promoteErrors(NSError)`

This is safe to do with NoError signals because we know at compile time that they won't actually produce errors, and therefore no casting needs to happen to change it to NSError.

Comment: let say `searchSignal` can accept nil string, so it can search empty string, but how about the different error result?, I'm trying to `flatmap` or `attemptMap` but how I handle different error like NSError to NoError, how to do that?  I can do `startWithNext` textSignal then inside it call the search signal.. but is reactivecocoa have trick to combine it? is there any other option?